# PHP stop function return from being overwritten

Tags: php

I've created two functions:

```
function script_start_time()
{
    $start_time = microtime(TRUE);
    return $start_time;
}
```

and

```
function script_end_time()
{   $start = script_start_time();
    $end_time = microtime(TRUE);
    $time_taken = $end_time - $start;
    $time_taken = round($time_taken, 4);
    echo 'Page generated in '.$time_taken.' seconds.';
}
```

`function script_start_time()` is ***called*** in `header.php` and `function script_end_time` is ***called*** in `footer.php`

I am trying to use `$start_time` value in `function script_end_time` without resorting to using `global` or `static`. Currently I get 0 in the echo, which I know is incorrect.

Where am I going wrong with these functions as it seems like `$start` is getting overwritten in `function script_end_time` instead of retaining the value from `function script_start_time`.

Comment: The point in your code when you get start time is just so close to the point when you get end time is so close that the difference is barely measurable in nanoseconds.... what is the point of this? You need to call start_script_time at the point when the script starts executing, then you can pass that value as a function argument to script_end_time()

Comment: `function script_start_time()` is **called** in `header.php` and `function script_end_time` is **called** in `footer.php`

Comment: It doesn't matter where the function is __defined__.... it matters where the function is __called__

Comment: Just put e.g. `sleep(2);` between your two microtime calls to simulate code that takes time...

Comment: @MarkBaker, question updated to be more readable

Comment: Your second function calls the first, so it doesn't matter if you call the first in the header.  If you want to measure the time between the start of the page and the end of the page, you'll have to assign the first time and then feed it into the second.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is your `script_start_time` function never **saves** the value of `$start_time` and instead always overwrites it anytime the function is called. So you're effectively asking for the current time anytime you call the function.

If you adjust your code slightly then it should work as expected:

```
function script_start_time()
{
    // SAVE the value of $start_time the first time it is requested
    static $start_time;
    if (empty($start_time))
    {
        $start_time = microtime(TRUE);
    }
    return $start_time;
}

function script_end_time()
{   
    $start = script_start_time();
    $end_time = microtime(TRUE);
    $time_taken = $end_time - $start;
    $time_taken = round($time_taken, 4);
    echo 'Page generated in '.$time_taken.' seconds.';
}

script_start_time();

usleep(5000);

script_end_time(); // Page generated in 0.0052 seconds.
```

Example: https://eval.in/861112

Answer (score 2):

```
function script_start_time()
{
    return microtime(TRUE);
}

function script_end_time($start_time)
{   
    $end_time = microtime(TRUE);
    $time_taken = $end_time - $start_time;
    $time_taken = round($time_taken, 4);
    echo 'Page generated in '.$time_taken.' seconds.';
}

$start_time = script_start_time();

usleep(4000);

script_end_time($start_time);
```

Comment: You're not using the passed in `$start_time` in your second function: https://eval.in/861121

Comment: Maybe the `$start_time` variable could be not in the same scope, and it does not work

Comment: Without using static variable, you need to take care to use on same scope @OsDev

Answer (score 1):

Rather than use the same function to save the start time and retrieve it, you could use a class:

```
class Timer {
    private static $start_time;

    public static function start() {
        self::$start_time = microtime(TRUE);
    }

    public static function show_time_since_start() {
        $end_time = microtime(TRUE);
        $time_taken = $end_time - self::$start_time;
        $time_taken = round($time_taken, 4);
        echo 'Page generated in '.$time_taken.' seconds.';
    }
}
```

Then at the beginning of the script you call:

```
Timer::start();
```

and at the end you do:

```
Timer::show_time_since_start();
```

Actually, I wouldn't put the `echo` statement in the function. I would just make a function that returns `$time_taken`, and do the printing in the caller.

And instead of just one timer, you could change the class so `$start_time` is an object property rather than a class property, and you could then create multiple timers that each remember a different start time.